# create SQL from given schema

Tags: sql

I am an SQL beginner and am not sure how to create the SQL (mySQL database) for the following query:

Find for each small and medium enterprise in UK, its identifier and total number of its employees who are living in UK. A SME is a company with less than 250 employees worldwide.

A person lives in pcountry. A company is located in ccountry. A person can work for several companies. (pid, cid) is composite key of workfor.

The schema:

```
person(pid (pkey), pname, pcountry)  
workfor(pid, cid)  
company(cid (pkey), cname, ccountry)
```

Sample data:
person(3, 'Eric Jackson', 'UK')
workfor(3, 5)
company(5, 'ACME', 'UK')

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You must have tried something when thinking about how to tackle this problem.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Please specify that next time.

Comment: Please post some sample data as well as your code you've already tried

Comment: The data you have provided is incomplete. How would you identify employees living in UK? You only have a City column. How would you associate this city column to UK? You will need a Country table and a mapping between City and Country to identify "Cities within UK".

Comment: Just as an example, if an employee's City is named "London", how would you know if this is London, England (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London), London, Ohio (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London,_Ohio) or London, Kentucky (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London,_Kentucky)